# System.InvalidCastException: Conversion from string ""IB"" to type 'Single' is not valid

Tags: vb.net, ssis

I am working in SSIS.  I have a flat file with one column feeding a script task that outputs 24 columns.  My script task is throwing this error:

System.InvalidCastException: Conversion from string ""IB"" to type 'Single' is not valid. ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

My flat file connection string, the input column, and all the output columns are set to unicode strings.

My VB.Net code is as follows:

```
Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)

If Not Row.Column0_IsNull AndAlso
        Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Row.Column0.Trim) Then


    Dim strColumns As String() = Row.Column0.Split(CChar(";"))

    If strColumns.Length <> 17 Then Exit Sub


    Output0Buffer.AddRow()
    Output0Buffer.Column = strColumns(0)
    Output0Buffer.Column1 = strColumns(1)
    Output0Buffer.Column2 = strColumns(2)
    Output0Buffer.Column3 = strColumns(3)
    Output0Buffer.Column4 = strColumns(4)
    Output0Buffer.Column5 = strColumns(5)
    Output0Buffer.Column6 = strColumns(6)
    Output0Buffer.Column7 = strColumns(7)
    Output0Buffer.Column8 = strColumns(8)
    Output0Buffer.Column9 = strColumns(9)
    Output0Buffer.Column10 = strColumns(10)
    Output0Buffer.Column11 = strColumns(11)
    Output0Buffer.Column12 = strColumns(12)
    Output0Buffer.Column13 = strColumns(13)
    Output0Buffer.Column14 = strColumns(14)
    Output0Buffer.Column15 = strColumns(15)
    Output0Buffer.Column16 = strColumns(16)

    End If

End Sub
```

To my knowledge, I am not using a float or a single anywhere in my code or my connection string.

The code throws the following exception:

Conversion from string ""IB"" to type 'Single' is not valid.

at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToSingle(String Value, NumberFormatInfo NumberFormat)
   at SC_5230962b79f144d082bc4f4027a93d01.ScriptMain.Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
   at SC_5230962b79f144d082bc4f4027a93d01.UserComponent.Input0_ProcessInput(Input0Buffer Buffer)
   at SC_5230962b79f144d082bc4f4027a93d01.UserComponent.ProcessInput(Int32 InputID, String InputName, PipelineBuffer Buffer, OutputNameMap OutputMap)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponent.ProcessInput(Int32 InputID, PipelineBuffer buffer)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.ProcessInput(Int32 inputID, PipelineBuffer buffer)

The exception window says this is in my script task, but the breakpoint at the beginning of the code never seems to get triggered.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

David

Comment: What line was the exception thrown on? Did you look at the exception? Did you debug the code?

Answer (score 0):

My apologies to all.  The data is a mess, and I had to reconstruct the text file.  Please ignore.  Thank you.